# Is it possible to select a field from a table, but override it with a new value in the select statement?

Tags: teradata

I am creating a view like this:

Let's say I originally have this:

`select * from mydb.mytable`

`mydb.mytable` has a field called `FirstName`, but I want to transform its value in the select statement.  Conceptually, I want to do this:

`select *, upper(firstname) firstname from mydb.mytable`

The problem is that `*` is already returning FirstName, so adding another column of the same name to the select breaks the SQL.  To get it to work, I have to list each field like this:

`select upper(firstname) firstname, lastname, city, state, zip`

This is just one example, but the table I really want to use this with has 30+ columns.  I don't like the idea of having to list out each column because adding a new field to the table means I have to modify the SQL (ordinal field position doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's the way SQL is designed, it's not a specific Teradata problem.

You want something like "select * but firstname" and no DBMS has implemented such a syntax.

Btw, one of (my) basic SQL rules is: never write "SELECT *" :-)

Comment: You're right, I really shouldn't have called it a problem because it isn't.  However, I don't think `select *` is a bad thing so long as you're not relying on ordinal column positions.  Otherwise, it could get you into trouble.

Comment: What if you add a new column to the table? You have to recreate the view anyway as "select * " will not include the new column.

Comment: Right, but simply building a view is a lot easier than adding a field and then building it.  It seems as though you're saying, "Well, while you're there, you may as well just add the field, too."  Are there any objective reasons why you should never use `select *`?  What are the measurable implications of doing this?

Comment: 1. A user who checks the definition of the view doesn't have any clue what is returned. Similar to using * in a SEELCT. 2. A column added to the table will not be returned by the view (without REPLACE VIEW SELECT *). 3. If you need a redefinition of a column in a base view (i.e. a 1:1 view of the base table) you should change your data model instead, e.g. FirstName VARCHAR(40) UPPERCASE

Comment: Not trying to argue, but: 1) the dev will still see the select from the table if they view def on the view.  Yes, they would then have to take the extra step of viewing def on the table, but that's not really what I'd call an implication.  2)  I already addressed this in my previous comment when I said "building a view is a lot easier than...".  3) Agreed.  What's happening in my case, though, is that a manually updated table field is being replaced by a calculated value in a view, so it's a one-off situation.

Answer (score 0):

As dnoeth says, that's just how SQL works.  Also, I'd reinforce his comment about never using `select *`, especially in a view.

To address concerns like this, I keep the table and view DDL together in code.  Whenever you change the table definition, you change the view definition at the same time. That way, whenever you add or remove columns from your table (your stated concern), your view always remains current.